# Typescript IOC in case of node

Tags: node.js, typescript, inversion-of-control, node-modules

I am wondering how would you use typescript IOC specifically node app.

In case of [external module-based architecture](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/) there is no any classes in the app. Just pure modules because my app heavily depends on node_modules.

How would I integrate IOC solution in such case? Any thoughts?

Here is my specific case I want to use IOC for:

I have mongoose model:

```
interface IStuffModel extends IStuff, mongoose.Document { }   

var Stuff= mongoose.model<IStuffModel>('Stuff', Schemas.stuffSchema);

export = Stuff;
```

And related fake class:

```
export class Stuff implements IStuff { 
 //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would I integrate IOC solution in such case

Here is a very popular library that I recommend : https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

## External modules

Using external modules doesn't change the code at all. Instead of

```
kernel.bind(new TypeBinding<FooBarInterface>("FooBarInterface", FooBar));
```

### Production

You just have

```
import {ProdFooBar} from "./prodFooBar";
kernel.bind(new TypeBinding<FooBarInterface>("FooBarInterface", ProdFooBar));
```

### Test

```
import {MockFooBar} from "./mockFooBar";
kernel.bind(new TypeBinding<FooBarInterface>("FooBarInterface", MockFooBar));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Basarat indicated in his answer, I have developed an IoC container called InversifyJS with advanced dependency injection features like contextual bindings.

You need to follow *3 basic steps* to use it:

#### 1. Add annotations

The annotation API is based on Angular 2.0:

```
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";

@injectable()
class Katana implements IKatana {
    public hit() {
        return "cut!";
    }
}

@injectable()
class Shuriken implements IShuriken {
    public throw() {
        return "hit!";
    }
}

@injectable()
class Ninja implements INinja {

    private _katana: IKatana;
    private _shuriken: IShuriken;

    public constructor(
        @inject("IKatana") katana: IKatana,
        @inject("IShuriken") shuriken: IShuriken
    ) {
        this._katana = katana;
        this._shuriken = shuriken;
    }

    public fight() { return this._katana.hit(); };
    public sneak() { return this._shuriken.throw(); };

}
```

#### 2. Declare bindings

The binding API is based on Ninject:

```
import { Kernel } from "inversify";

import { Ninja } from "./entities/ninja";
import { Katana } from "./entities/katana";
import { Shuriken} from "./entities/shuriken";

var kernel = new Kernel();
kernel.bind<INinja>("INinja").to(Ninja);
kernel.bind<IKatana>("IKatana").to(Katana);
kernel.bind<IShuriken>("IShuriken").to(Shuriken);

export default kernel;
```

#### 3. Resolve dependencies

The resolution API is based on Ninject:

```
import kernel = from "./inversify.config";

var ninja = kernel.get<INinja>("INinja");

expect(ninja.fight()).eql("cut!"); // true
expect(ninja.sneak()).eql("hit!"); // true
```

The latest release (2.0.0) supports many use cases:

- Kernel modules
- Kernel middleware
- Use classes, string literals or Symbols as dependency identifiers
- Injection of constant values
- Injection of class constructors
- Injection of factories
- Auto factory
- Injection of providers (async factory)
- Activation handlers (used to inject proxies)
- Multi injections
- Tagged bindings
- Custom tag decorators
- Named bindings
- Contextual bindings
- Friendly exceptions (e.g. Circular dependencies)

You can learn more about it at https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

In the particular context of Node.js there is [a hapi.js example that uses InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-code-samples/tree/master/hapi).

Comment: I don’t understand how this helps when OP is specifically asking for node example without classes. I’m sure it’s a great library, but it is hard to understand how one would make it work in a regular classless node app.

Comment: If you are not using OOP and you are not planning to have classes in your source code I would not recommend trying to use InversifyJS. InversifyJS doesn't support dependency injection in functions for example. I think InversifyJS makes a lot of sense in OOP and DDD code bases but not in FP code bases. If you are working with functions you can try partial application instead: https://medium.com/javascript-inside/currying-partial-application-f1365d5fad3f